# Oracle finding duplicate rows that are consecutive for a given field

Tags: oracle, duplicates

We have some tables in an Oracle 19c database that were put in place many years ago for audit purposes. This 'audit' table is being generated by a trigger on update/delete to another table "widget". It is not checking to see if the new data matches the old data, so there are a lot of rows that are identical in everything but timestamp. I am not looking for comments on fixing the auditing as there many solutions to that mess. We are currently just stopping the bleeding until a better solution can be implemented.

My question is how to cut my existing audit data down to only the records that actually changed. These tables have grown to the point that it is impacting some of our processes.

auditWidget table data:

| dataRowID | widgetID | widgetDesc | timestampOfTableUpdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1/29/2016 12:12:55 PM |
| 2 | 2 | test | 1/29/2016 12:13:55 PM |
| 3 | 1 | A | 1/29/2016 12:14:55 PM |
| 4 | 1 | A | 1/29/2016 12:15:55 PM |
| 5 | 2 | test | 1/29/2016 12:16:55 PM |
| 6 | 1 | c | 1/29/2016 12:17:55 PM |
| 7 | 1 | b | 1/29/2016 12:18:55 PM |
| 8 | 2 | d | 1/29/2016 12:19:55 PM |
| 9 | 1 | A | 1/29/2016 12:20:55 PM |

As you can see, nothing has changed between row 1,3 and 4, or between 2 and 5. These rows should never have been created. I am trying to find a way to identify/delete the entries that don't show any change in the widget table. My final data would look like this:

| dataRowID | widgetID | widgetDesc | timestampOfTableUpdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1/29/2016 12:12:55 PM |
| 2 | 2 | b | 1/29/2016 12:13:55 PM |
| 6 | 1 | c | 1/29/2016 12:17:55 PM |
| 7 | 1 | b | 1/29/2016 12:18:55 PM |
| 8 | 2 | d | 1/29/2016 12:19:55 PM |
| 9 | 1 | A | 1/29/2016 12:20:55 PM |

LAG only looks at the previous row which might contain a different widgetID. There are thousands of widgetIDs. There is also potentially many identical rows per widgetID in a row. Are there any solutions out there short of looping through the data and conditionally doing something with it row by row? Any direction would be appreciated.

SQL to create data for testing:

CREATE TABLE AUDITWIDGET
(
"DATAROWID" NUMBER(*,0),
"WIDGETID" NUMBER(*,0),
"WIDGETDESC" VARCHAR2(30),
"TIMESTAMPOFTABLEUPDATE" DATE);

Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (1,1,'A',sysdate - interval '100' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (2,2,'test',sysdate - interval '99' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (3,1,'A',sysdate - interval '98' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (4,1,'A',sysdate - interval '97' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (5,2,'test',sysdate - interval '96' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (6,1,'c',sysdate - interval '95' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (7,1,'b',sysdate - interval '94' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (8,1,'d',sysdate - interval '93' minute);
Insert into AUDITWIDGET (datarowID,widgetID,widgetDesc,timeStampOfTableUpdate) values (9,1,'A',sysdate - interval '92' minute);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution to only `SELECT` the relevant data is to use `LAG()`. For example:

```
select *,
from (
  select t.*,
    lag(widgetdesc) over(
      partition by widgetid 
      order by timestampOfTableUpdate
    ) as prev_desc
  from my_table t
) x
where widgetdesc <> prev_desc
```

Comment: Unless there is something to LAG that I'm missing, this solution would only work if the duplicate was on the previous row. In my case, the duplicate could be on any row and there could be multiple duplicate rows. See the example data.

Comment: @MattInVail For example, rowID #3 has the same value as #1, so this query filters it out. Then #4 has the same value of #3, so this query filters it out as well. #5 has the same value as #2; out it goes. Please include the special case you are thinking about.

Comment: Sorry, You are right. I didn't understand what partition by was doing. This is almost correct. With the original dataset it would have produced the correct results.  It does not account for a record that changes back to it's original state. I added row #9 to the question as the example. The records for 1 that we would want to keep are A c b A (two A's) because these are the records that show a change in the data. This does seem to remove many of the duplicates. I will keep working with this to see if I can find a variation that gets all of them. Thanks.

Comment: @MattInVail #9 (`A`) will have a different value compared to its previous row #7 (`b`), so it will stay included.

Comment: Yes, sorry again. I added the script to create the data to the original question and with some minor edits to your answer it does work. There was an extra comma and it needed 'or prev_desc is null'  to account for the first entries per ID.

select *
from (
  select t.*,
    lag(widgetdesc) over(
      partition by widgetid 
      order by timestampOfTableUpdate
    ) as prev_desc
  from auditWidget t
) x
where widgetdesc <> prev_desc
or prev_desc is null

Answer (score 0):

Delete duplicates, then:

```
delete from auditwidget a
  where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                   from auditwidget b
                   where b.widgetid = a.widgetid
                     and b.widgetdesc = a.widgetdesc
                  );
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't account for data that changed from A to B and back to A. If we are trying to track changes in the data, then adding a record for changing A to A is unnecessary, but if it changed form A -> B -> A then all three rows would be needed. The original dataset didn't have an example of this, so I added one more row. Thanks for the response though.